# Is there a simple way to use django's template engine for django's own views and jinja2 engine for my own views?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

- For convenience, I use a custom Jinja2 template loader for all views of my Django project with [this method](http://exyr.org/2010/Jinja-in-Django/). Thus No matter where I write my own view funcitons, I don't have to write or declare anything special for Jinja2 engine(because I changed the default template loader to Jinja2 in settings.py at the beginning).
- But when I want to visit urls that use Django's own views , such as `admin.site.urls`'s `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`, it fails (apparently) .
- I've tried to convert all the html files in Django's own admin folder to the ones Jinja2 engine can parse , but I quickly give up, as there are so many filters or tags to be convert, also it is not a good idea to modify source code.
- So, is there a simple way to use django's template engine for django's own views and jinja2 engine for the remaining views? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, its theory is : **For every templateResponse, first try Django template engine, if `TemplateSyntaxError` is raised, then try jinja2 engine** (just like before).

It works, but I am not sure if there are any potential erros.

```
import os
import sys

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.template.base import TemplateDoesNotExist,TemplateSyntaxError
from django.template.loader import BaseLoader
from django.utils._os import safe_join
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
from django.utils import six
import jinja2

if six.PY2:
    fs_encoding = sys.getfilesystemencoding() or sys.getdefaultencoding()
app_template_dirs = []
for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    try:
        mod = import_module(app)
    except ImportError as e:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
    template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(mod.__file__), 'templates')
    if os.path.isdir(template_dir):
        if six.PY2:
            template_dir = template_dir.decode(fs_encoding)
        app_template_dirs.append(template_dir)

# It won't change, so convert it to a tuple to save memory.
app_template_dirs = tuple(app_template_dirs)

ALL_PATH = settings.JINJA2_TEMPLATE_DIRS + app_template_dirs

class jinja2Template(jinja2.Template):
    def render(self, context):
        # flatten the Django Context into a single dictionary.
        context_dict = {}
        for d in context.dicts:
            context_dict.update(d)
        return super(jinja2Template, self).render(context_dict)

class Loader(BaseLoader):
    is_usable = True
    env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(ALL_PATH))
    env.template_class = jinja2Template

    def load_template(self, template_name, template_dirs=None):
        # this is the key method.
        try:
            return super(Loader,self).load_template(template_name, ALL_PATH)
        except TemplateSyntaxError:
            template = self.env.get_template(template_name)
            return template, template.filename
        except jinja2.TemplateNotFound:
            raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name)

    def get_template_sources(self, template_name, template_dirs=None):
        if not template_dirs:
            template_dirs = app_template_dirs
        for template_dir in template_dirs:
            try:
                yield safe_join(template_dir, template_name)
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                raise
            except ValueError:
                pass

    def load_template_source(self, template_name, template_dirs=None):
        for filepath in self.get_template_sources(template_name, template_dirs):
            try:
                with open(filepath, 'rb') as fp:
                    return (fp.read().decode(settings.FILE_CHARSET), filepath)
            except IOError:
                pass
        raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name)
```